# svn No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: svn

I want install svn server on my local machine. I have installed CollabNetSubversion-server-1.8.4-1-Win32.
Create repository: `svnadmin create myrepo`. My conf file looks like:

```
[general]
anon-access = read
auth-access = write
# password-db = passwdle.
# authz-db = authz
# groups-db = groups
realm = khris
# hooks-env = hooks-env
[sasl]
# use-sasl = true
# min-encryption = 0
# max-encryption = 256
```

Also I have installed Tortoise SVN, create folder `myclientrepo`, and try command Checkout. Set Url of the repository: `svn://localhost/myrepo`. I got:

```
 Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://localhost/myrepo'
 Can't connect to host 'localhost': No connection could be made because the target machine actively  refused it.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Make sure that the server process has started, that it's listening on the desired port and host, and that firewall rules have been added.

Comment: @khris were you able to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

- Did you run `svnserve`? That's the Subversion server for the `svn://` protocol.
- Is something blocking port 3690? That's the port that `svnserve` uses by default. Make sure your Windows firewall isn't on and that your router isn't blocking that port.

One more thing: The way you have it configured:

```
anon-access = read
auth-access = write
```

Means that anonymous users have read-only access, and you need to log into your system to have read/write access.

However, you also have:

```
# password-db = passwd
# authz-db = authz
# groups-db = groups
```

All commented out which means you have no authorization database to allow users to log into your Subversion repository in order to be able to commit changes.

Easiest thing to do is to remove the `#` in front of `password-db`. Inside your repository where this configuration file sits is a file called `passed`. You can use that to configure your users and passwords. The directions are inside that file.

Comment: What would happen if we don't specify the anon-access and auth-access  parameters? In my situation everyone can access the repo with svn://path commands. I haven't defined any access methods in my startup script. How can this be happening?

Comment: The default way svnserve works is to allow read-only access to anon and read-write access to authorized users. However, if you don't specify authorized users in some way, no one gets read-write access.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What if I want to pass the authorization decision to Redmine? I mean I want the repo dirs to be authorized by Redmine's project user settings. This setup is already in place in our old server's separate Redmine 1.2.1 + CollabnetSVN 1.6.6 configuration. Now I'm trying to migrate it to Bitnami Redmine 2.5 stack. I've copied the repo with svnadmin dump/create/load commands but the access settings weren't copied. Should I use "svnadmin hotcopy" instead? If I set the access rights manually via the conf file, how will I control them later from Redmine?

Comment: I don't know enough about Redmine to know how its user setup and permissioning works. I believe it supports [LDAP](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/redmineldap). If you can use LDAP, setting up Apache httpd with Subversion and access via LDAP is quite common. You can also do this via [SASL and `svnserve`](http://michaelcamden.me/?p=27).